# How to paste the text to the next line using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have copied some text from the website and then pasted it into the text file. And also I did the same thing to paste the second text using the "Append To File" keyword.
I want to paste the first text in the first row and the second text in the next row. How could I do that?

This is what I have so far,

*** Test Cases ***

TC_01

```
Open Browser    ${BASE_URL}     gc
EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT    window.scrollTo(200,400)
sleep  5s

${Text} =  Get Text    xpath=//div[2]/md-card/header/h2
${Value} =  Get Text    css=.recommended-size
createFile     C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt      ${Text}
Append To File      C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt    ${Space}
Append To File      C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt   ${Value}

log to console   success
sleep  2s
```

[image: Screenshot 1 - Result]

I got the result as the above screenshot, and what I want to do is, I want to paste the "1km" on the next line.

Please help to solve this issue. Any guidance and advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
${Text} =  Catenate    SEPARATOR=    Text1    \n     Text2     \n 
${Value}     set variable  Text4
createFile          ${EXECDIR}/File.txt      ${Text}
Append To File      ${EXECDIR}/File.txt   ${Value}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a newline character to separate the text between different lines.

You can use the following code to add a newline character before appending the second text to the file:

*** Test Cases ***

TC_01

```
Open Browser ${BASE_URL} gc
EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT window.scrollTo(200,400)
sleep 5s

${Text} = Get Text xpath=//div[2]/md-card/header/h2
${Value} = Get Text css=.recommended-size
createFile C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt ${Text}
Append To File C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt \n
Append To File C:/MyProjects/Records/File.txt ${Value}

log to console success
sleep 2s
```